# Convert Day of year to NSDate (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have the day of the year and I want to convert it to NSDate.

Example: 
today is day 60 of 2015.
I want to convert 60 to March 1st, 2015

Comment: What code have you tried? I may be easier to add this functionality to existing library, like Timepiece: https://github.com/naoty/Timepiece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let myDay = 60
let myYear = 2015

let myDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: myYear, month: 1, day: myDay, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)! //Mar 1, 2015, 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: Want to break that into multiple lines so people can actually read it, please?